# Android Kotlin - cannot resolve firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to include Firebase (specifically Firebase Authentication) to my project. I'm an iOS developer that's trying to learn Kotlin, so it has been like 4 years since I last touched Android/Android Studio (and definitely never touched Kotlin before).

So my knowledge of Android is a bit covered in dust.

I also tried to implement Clean Architecture to make a good start with my app. So I added a new module like described here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3595916-clean-architecture-tutorial-for-android-getting-started. I added a `core` module and then in that module I added packages: `domain`, `data` and `interactors`.

I added this to my app's `build.gradle` in the block `dependencies`:

`implementation project(':core')`

So my app knows my module `core`.

The `build.gradle` file of my `core` module looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.26'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.26'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0")
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

You can see I also added `Dagger` for dependency injection. This resolves fine.

This is the root Gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the app Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.charlotteerpels.travellyn"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.26'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'

    implementation project(':core')

    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.26'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

The Gradle build/sync finishes without errors.

But when I try to do the following in a simple class with a simple function, I get an error.

`val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

The error is: `Unresolved reference: FirebaseAuth`.
Android Studio also doesn't provide to import something. So I tried adding the import by myself on top of the file, right below the `package` line.

`import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth`, but that doesn't resolve either. In my file, `firebase` in the import and `FirebaseAuth` in the function stays red.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the steps here, importantly the google() repos and applying the google services: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Yes I did :( I'll post my project Gradle file and app Gradle file also in the post

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make sure you are including the google repos for it to find firebase.

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

a) in the project level gradle

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

b) in the app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// Add the following line:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

android {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: @Charlotte1993 unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue :( I made an empty project with only the code i provided and can use firebase with no issue. If you could give a repo where you issue is happening maybe i could help find the issue